# If $a,b,c\in\mathbb{R},$ such that $a\geq 2$, $b\geq 5$, $c\geq 5$ and $2a^2+b^2+c^2=69$. Prove that $12a+13b+11c \geq 155.$

Tags: inequality

So,I am trying to prove the following inequality without using the Lagrange multipliers:

If $a,b,c\in\mathbb{R},$ such that $a\geq 2$, $b\geq 5$, $c\geq 5$ and $2a^2+b^2+c^2=69$. Prove that
$$12a+13b+11c \geq 155.$$

My try:
$\bullet a\geq 2, b\geq 5, c\geq 5,2a^2+b^2+c^2=69 \rightarrow 2 \le a<4,5 \le b,c \le 6.$

But,I don't know how to proceed further.
Any help would be highly appreciated.Thank you!

Comment: Use Lagrange Multipliers to minimize the function.

Comment: @geetha290krm,how to prove it without using the Lagrange multipliers?

Comment: This has been answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2820588/find-the-minimizer-of-a-12a13b11c).

Answer (score 0):

Let $a = 2 + x, b = 5 + y, c = 5 + z$. Then $x, y, z \ge 0$.

We have $2a^2 + b^2 + c^2 - 69
= 2x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + 8x + 10y + 10z - 11 = 0$.

We want to prove that $12x + 13y + 11z \ge 11$.

We split into two cases:

(1) If $x > 1$ or $y > 1$ or $z > 1$, we have $12x + 13y + 11z \ge 11$.

(2) If $x, y, z \in [0, 1]$, we have
$$2x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + 8x + 10y + 10z
\le 2x + y + z + 8x + 10y + 10z
= 10x + 11y + 11 z $$
which results in $10x + 11y + 11z \ge 11$.
Thus, we have $12x + 13y + 11z
\ge 10x + 11y + 11 z \ge 11$.

We are done.

Comment: would you enlighten me why you have chosen the interval $[0,1]?$ Is there any motivation?

Comment: @Debrogli Because: (1) $12x + 13y + 11z \ge 11$, if $x \ge 1$, then $12x \ge 11$, if $y \ge 1$, then $13y \ge 1$, and if $z \ge 1$, then $11z \ge 11$. (2) $u \ge u^2$ for all $u \in [0, 1]$. I just want to eliminate the quadratic terms.

Comment: ,the question says $a,b,c\in\mathbb{R}.$ So,I think you have to prove the inequality in all real numbers,not only $[0,1].$ Kindly, correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @Debrogli Did you notice the condition? It is:  $a,b,c\in\mathbb{R},$ such that $a\geq 2$, $b\geq 5$, $c\geq 5$.

Comment: ,Oh sorry sir! But we have to prove the inequality in $a\geq2,b\geq5,c\geq5.$ Why you have chosen only the interval $[0,1]?$

Comment: @Debrogli First, I let $a = 2 + x, b = 5 + y, c = 5 + z$. The condition becomes $x, y, z \ge 0$. Then I split into two cases: (1) $x \ge 1$ or $y \ge 1$ or $z \ge 1$; (2) $x, y, z \in [0, 1]$.